# How i can set image into right bottom edge of textview with flowing text around?

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview, constraints

I need to set image into right bottom edge of layout and have text above it and on left side, but it shouldn't overlap my image: [this done with constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFDX0.png)

I can do something like above with constraints. But I don't want to have spaces on right or on bottom. Also i tried drawableEnd. Couldn't archieve desired result too.

Comment: Views don't have cutouts like that. You have to do something more complex or more simply move it out of the way somewhere else.

Comment: You can if course simply do two TextViews if you can cut the text apart.

Answer (score -1):

use Relativelayout.

place these two atts for imageview:

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

and these two for Textview:

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Imageview"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Comment: OP wants the text to flow directly above AND directly to the side of the ImageView (around it) without overlapping. I don't see how your answer does this.